# Is there a way that I can run only Cypress tests specific to the application files I changed?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I would like to run only specific Cypress tests related to the ***application*** files that I changed, but every time that I make a change all the integration tests are running. I've already checked a tool called cypress grep but it uses tags to map the tests but it is not dynamic or automatic since I need to set the tags and also add the tags manually in the pipeline.

Do you know an alternative tool to solve this issue?

Comment: How would you determine "related to the files that I changed"? Typically Cypress is used for high-level E2E/acceptance tests where it knows nothing about the implementation details.

Comment: We use cypress to write our integration tests, so we would like to run only the specific tests related to the files of the application that we changed.

Comment: You're thinking of unit tests which correspond to individual src files or groups thereof. Or are you using component testing?

Comment: Integration testing, what I would like to do is to run only the relevant integration tests related to the src files(application) files that I changed. Let's say I added a button on the booking page and then i only run the integrations tests related to that page.

Answer (score 1):

We are using nx with Angular, works quite well https://nx.dev/using-nx/affected. Not sure if it's suitable for your project and if it's worth setting up whole nx.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the [`find-cypress-specs`](https://github.com/bahmutov/find-cypress-specs) where you can get a list of changed specs, number, and by tags.

You'll have to form the Cypress run command in your YML file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Does this tool recognize the files of the application that were changed and run the tests specific to them?

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. No this will not. This will only check for changes in the cypress test files.